# Looking for a workaround to replace dnfdragora with yumex-dnf

Tags: fedora, dnf

Fedora 27 comes with `dnfdragora` package manager GUI, which is a disgusting and cruel parody on software, developed by someone who either hates their users, or lacks basic GUI design skills taught to college students during the 1st semester. It lacks important features which `yumex-dnf` had, namely

- Package Description
- Package Update Info
- Package Filelist
- Package Requirements

panels, and all panels of `dnfdragora` are non-resizable. On top of that scrolling jumps multiple pages at a time, making the monstrosity totally useless.

I thought that replacing it with `yumex-dnf` should be trivial, as it is in Fedora 26, and tried installing that package. But someone in their wisdom aliased `dnfdragora` in the repos as `yumex-dnf` thus making it impossible to install from a repo ("package already installed").

Building from sources is not possible due to an error which prevents complete installation of the build, and if running `yumex-dnf` from where `make install` puts it, it does not load and just freezes on an exception screen. I do not remember the entire text of the error, and no longer have a 27 installation to reproduce, as I need to do work and had to revert to 26 on a short notice.

Can anyone please explain what can be done to wipe out `dnfdragora` and install `yumex-dnf` on a fresh installation of Fedora 27?

Comment: Downvoters, what's your reason? This seems like a reasonable question to me and shows research and reasons.

Comment: Downvotes are probably by people that could not have known this was answerable without the error message. With 2 years hindsight, I am upvoting, even though the lack of error message is a poor example to others.

Answer (score 6):

This was intentional: In F27, [yumex-dnf was replaced with dnfdragora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Replace_yumex-dnf_with_dnfdragora) because yumex-dnf has been [abandoned by its authors](https://github.com/timlau/yumex-dnf/blob/develop/README.md).

What you need to do is (find someone to) take over development of yumex-dnf, and then get it re-added to Fedora.

You can also use another GUI, such as GNOME Software (the default GUI for installing packages).

You can also forgo a GUI package installer entirely. I've been using Fedora (and Red Hat before that) so long that I don't even think twice about using `dnf` at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The old package from Fedora 26 works in the new versions. Use this command to d/l or go to koji:

```
dnf download --releasever=26 yumex-dnf
```

Download and copy files from its cpio archive to the destinations. `mc` can extract from cpio inside the rpm.

This is a great workaround, considering that dnfdragora pins CPU for hours for no obvious reason and is horrendously slow - much slower than yumex used to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the classic yumex before dnf became a thing, this is what I did
on my Fedora 27 installation (as root):

```
mkdir YUMEX ;
cd YUMEX ;
wget -c https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/21/x86_64/y/yumex-3.0.17-1.fc21.noarch.rpm ;
yum -y install --downloadonly --downloaddir=. yumex-3.0.17-1.fc21.noarch.rpm ;
```

A bunch of Fedora 27 dependencies will be downloaded.  Check the ensure that
you're okay with installing those.  There should be 24 additional RPMs. Then...

```
yum -y install *.rpm
```

Now, you have the classic yumex.  I've never actually used yumex to install packages,
as I always install from the command line, but yumex has been a great tool for finding
packages.

- Yes, yes I know yum == dnf on Fedora 27; old habits...

Answer (score 1):

Easy ... On Fedora 32:

Just build `yumex-dnf-4.3.3-1.fc24.src.rpm`:
(https://github.com/timlau/yumex-dnf/releases)

1. Fetch most recent yumex-dnf Source RPM

   ```
   $ wget https://github.com/timlau/yumex-dnf/releases/download/yumex-dnf-4.3.3/yumex-dnf-4.3.3-1.fc24.src.rpm
   ```
2. Install `rpmbuild`

   ```
   $ dnf install rpm-build
   ```
3. Install build dependencies

   ```
   $ dnf builddep ./yumex-dnf-4.3.3-1.fc24.src.rpm
   ```
4. Build `yumex-dnf` RPM from Source RPM

   ```
   $ rpmbuild --rebuild ./yumex-dnf-4.3.3-1.fc24.src.rpm
   RPM built under ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/yumex-dnf-4.3.3-1.fc32.noarch.rpm
   ```
5. Install `yumex-dnf` from newly created rpm:

   ```
   $ dnf install ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/yumex-dnf-4.3.3-1.fc32.noarch.rpm
   ```

That's how it's done ...

Answer (score -1):

No need to goof around with `cpio` contents: you can just force `rpm` to install the package with `--nodeps` and blacklist `dnfdragora` in `dnf.conf` using `exclude=dnfdragora*` tag.